# WPF application runs faster in debug mode

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I've been working on a WPF application that visualizes complex functions
with colored rectangles on a canvas. At the moment about 40.000 rectangles are drawn at the same time when a button is clicked. The problem is that my applications needs few seconds if executed in debug mode (F5) whereas it takes up to one minute if it is executed without debbuging (Ctrl + F5) until all rectangles are drawn on the canvas. Analyzing the memory shows that the memory usage increases much faster in debug mode than in normal mode.

For better understanding:
I have a loop that goes through all complex numbers between (-5, -5) to (5, 5) in 0.05 steps. For each calculated value a color for a rectangle is evaluated depending on phase and magnitude.

Edit:
The loop starts after a button is clicked and c is an instance of the Complex Class and r, i double values to safe the current values of the complex number:

```
c = new Complex(-5, -5);
while(c.Real < 5){
r = c.Real;
rsum = 0.0d;
    while(c.Imaginary < 5){
    ShowRect(c);
    i = this.c.Imaginary;
    c = new Complex(r, i + 0.05);
    isum += 0.05d;
    }
r = c.Real;
c = new Complex(r + 0.05, -5);
rsum += 0.05d;
}


private void ShowRect(Complex c){
  //Some calculation stuff with res as result value
  rect = new Rectangle();
  //Setting the properties of the rectangle object
  rect.Fill = EvalColor(res);
  canvas.Children.Add(rect);

private SolidColorBrush EvalColor(Complex com){
 if(com.Phase <= -35 * Math.PI / 36)
    return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRGB(1, 1, 1));
 else if(...) 
 //same scheme for every statement
```

Does anyone know why it is like this? I just found one thread without any answers written years ago. Thankful for any help.

Greetings and have a nice day

Comment: Did you try to build your application in Release mode?

Comment: Yes, I did but did not help unfortunately.

Comment: _"Does anyone know why it is like this?"_ -- without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem? No, of course not. How could we? There is literally _zero_ information about your actual code in your question. We can't possibly know _anything_ about it, never mind why it behaves differently depending on whether the debugger is attached.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer.

Comment: Even before thinking about anything else, **do not create 40,000 brushes**. Whichever is that logic reuse the same brush for the same color.

Comment: So I tried to create a List with SolidColorBrush objects returning them if needed but now it takes even longer in both debug and non-debug to visualize the function.

Comment: For serious data-visualisation tasks in WPF you should paint directly to a texture surface using Direct2D instead of using WPF's visual tree system - it's intended for interactive UI components, not graphing and charts.

Comment: Thank you, I will look it up as well as using WriteableBitmap as suggested in another thread.